# functional call issue in R

Tags: r, weibull

I am trying to calculate the cost rate with a Weibull lifetime distribution in R with the following code:

```
CR_age <- function(T,lambda,k,cpm,ccm)
{
  cum <- function(T,lambda,k)
  { 
    return(1 - exp((-T/lambda)^k))
  }
  survival <- function(T,lambda,k)
  {
    return(exp((-T/lambda)^k))
  }
  mean_cost <- ccm * cum(T,lambda,k) + cpm * survival(T,lambda,k)
  cycle_length <- Vectorize(survival, "T")
  mean_cycle_length <- integrate(cycle_length, 0, T)
  costRate <- mean_cost / mean_cycle_length$value

  return(costRate)
}
```

as I call the function

```
 CR_age(2,0.1,1,3,1)
```

I receive a warning from R saying that :

```
Error in (function (T, lambda, k)  : 
  argument "lambda" is missing, with no default
```

May I ask what would be the reason in this case? Is that I did not pass the argument lambda in CR_age to the functions cum and survival?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you maybe should use `integrate(function(x) cycle_length(x,lambda,k), 0, T)`

Comment: You vectorize survival but don't give defaults for the other parameters. In the next line when you try to integrate it had nothing to use for lambda (or k)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give all the parameters of you function `survival` in the `Vectorize` and `integrate` functions

```
CR_age <- function(Te,lambda,k,cpm,ccm)
{
  cum <- function(Te,lambda,k)
  { 
    return(1 - exp((-Te/lambda)^k))
  }
  survival <- function(Te,lambda,k)
  {
    return(exp((-Te/lambda)^k))
  }
  mean_cost <- ccm * cum(Te,lambda,k) + cpm * survival(Te,lambda,k)
  cycle_length <- Vectorize(survival, vectorize.args =c("Te", "lambda", "k"))
  mean_cycle_length <- integrate(cycle_length, 0, Te, lambda, k)
  costRate <- mean_cost / mean_cycle_length$value

  return(costRate)
}

CR_age(2,0.1,1,3,1)
```

> [1] 10

Answer (score 0):

You miss your arguments `lambda` and `k` for the line `mean_cycle_length <- integrate(cycle_length, 0, T)`.

Maybe you should update it to

```
mean_cycle_length <- integrate(function(x) cycle_length(x,lambda,k), 0, T)
```

then you can run your code without error, i.e.,

```
> CR_age(2,0.1,1,3,1)
[1] 10
```